# Create a PDF from an off screen NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to create a pdf containing screenshots of a number of different `NSViewController's` which I create off screen (so the user doesn't see any change).

I've been able to get this to work for on screen views added to the main `NSWindow`, but so far have been unable to get the same effect without adding the view to the window. I've also tried creating a new `NSWindow` which has bounds that are off the screen and adding the View's to that, but it didn't work.

I've managed to get an `NSImage` from an off screen `NSView` using the following:-

```
    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapImageRep = [offScreenView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:offScreenView.bounds];
    [offScreenView cacheDisplayInRect:offScreenView.bounds toBitmapImageRep:bitmapImageRep];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:bitmapImageRep.size];
    [image addRepresentation:bitmapImageRep];
```

But I can't get from this to a `PDFDocument` because its not in the correct image representation. Is there any way to convert or is there another way to do this entirely?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

This may get you started:

```
NSData  *pdfData=[offScreenView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[offScreenView frame]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd already tried that. It produces a pdf correctly but for some reason the view isn't laid out correctly as it is in the nib or if it's set to the current view, instead the contents of the view are all placed at the bottom overlapping each other. I've checked and the frame is definitely set correctly. Not sure why this would happen?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout? I wonder if one of the calls that are normally called implicitly when a window is brought on screen is missing, and the layout isn't done yet. Try something like `[offScreenView layout];`.

Comment: No I'm not using auto layout and calling layout didn't change things. It's strange because when I use the NSBitmapImageRep method I showed above the layout is correct. But I can't get from that to a pdf!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what happens when you use the NSBitmapImageRep first, then follow that with the -dataWithPDFInsideRect: method?

Comment: No change, the image file I output is laid out correctly but the pdf isn't. Very confusing!

Comment: I somewhat solved the problem by just using the `NSBitmapImageRep` method, then making this a pdf by putting the resultant `NSImage` into an `NSImageView`, then calling `[imageView dataWithPDFInsideRect:rect]`. This is two steps when I'd rather use one but it works!